What is the process to control the number of decimal places in a Qweb report?
I have set up my database to display prices four decimal places, but I prefer my report to show only two decimal places.
I have attempted both of these methods but neither of them produce any alterations in the printed version of my PDF quote.
<span t-field="line.price_unit" t-options="{'widget': 'monetary', 'display_currency': doc.pricelist_id.currency_id, 'digits': 2}" />

<span t-field="line.price_unit" t-options="{'widget': 'monetary', 'display_currency': doc.pricelist_id.currency_id, 'presicion': 2}" />

